# JavaScript Modal not working and showing undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck on this modal I'm trying to build at the moment. Basically I have a card that when you click a modal should pop up. I've got a script tag in my HTML file for it. When I click the modal, nothing appears and when I inspected the page I get in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: openPopup is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (modal.html:16:74) onclick @ modal.html:16
```

This is my first time attempting to build a modal and I thought I defined it but clearly not or not where I should. I'll attach my HTML below, thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?     family=Bebas+Neue&family=Poiret+One&family=Raleway:wght@300&family=Reenie+Beanie&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-category omnifood">
            <img src="omnifood.jpg" alt="omnifood" onclick='openPopup()'>
            <p class="text-card"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="popup" id="popup">
            <h2>Omnifood</h2>
            <p>Omnifood is a mock delivery service I created to demonstrate web page responsiveness, CSS styling, and an introduction to basic JQuery features.</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let popup = document.getElementById('popup');

        function openPopup(){
            popup.classList.add('open-popup');
        }
        function closePopup(){
            popup.classList.remove('open-popup');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVp0t.png)

Here's an image of what I'm seeing

Comment: Missing the ending quotation on `onclick="closePopup()`.

Answer (score 1):

When recreating your code, the following works for me. It may be your missing " after onclick=closePopup() which is causing the rest of your code to not load.

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup.open-popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-category omnifood">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="omnifood" onclick='openPopup()'>
        <p class="text-card"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup">
        <h2>Omnifood</h2>
        <p>Omnifood is a mock delivery service I created to demonstrate web page responsiveness, CSS styling, and an introduction to basic JQuery features.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      function openPopup(){
          popup.classList.add('open-popup');
      }
      function closePopup(){
          popup.classList.remove('open-popup');
      }
    </script>
</div>
```